# How to check for records that are older than today in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I've set up a timestamp field with extra set to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
It works but I have a question:

I'd like to check for all records which are older than today - how would I do that?

Comment: Older than today or older than 24 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use date_sub to make it easier

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_info < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM {your_table} 
WHERE {time_stamp_field} < CURDATE()
```

Or, you could do

```
SELECT * 
FROM  {your_table}
WHERE {time_stamp_field} <= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

So if `CURDATE()` returns 2011-05-16, `DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY )` evaluates to 2011-05-15.

Comment: It's `CURDATE()` not CUR_DATE()

Answer (score 1):

An example query for *older than today* (before midnight) would be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE timestamp_column < CURDATE();
```

Check out the [MySQL Date/Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more details. If you want *older than last 24 hours*, check out **fafnirbcrow's** answer

Comment: It's ambiguous but I suspect "records which are older than today" might mean something like "24 hours old".

Comment: this is older than now; not today.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that, by "older than today", you mean anything inserted before last night at midnight. If you mean older than 24 hours ago let me know (and edit your question).

Here's what you do:

1. Get yesterday's timestamp: `$timestamp = strtotime('24.00 yesterday')`;
2. Convert it in the mysql datetime format: `$mysql_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)`;
3. Do the query: `SELECT foo FROM bar WERE baz < $timestamp`.

Comment: A pure MySQL solution is better in the event that the database is on a separate server.

Comment: @jason you mean, with different time settings? because otherwise I can't see any problem.

Comment: Yes. It's common that the time for MySQL and PHP could be different or even have different timezone settings. Especially when on separate servers. If the user is storing the date in MySQL (as evident by the `ON UPDATE`) then they should be comparing in MySQL.

Comment: +1 Doing it with PHP allows for the query to be cached whereas using MySQL's built in functions does not.