# mysql query for all records not today

Tags: php, mysql

How would I return all rows that are **not** from today? Im running a query on results returned from this. each row has a mysql timestamp. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: sql query (timestamp)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022714/php-sql-query-timestamp)

Comment: @Evan Mulawski I think you may be right, I didnt see that post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * from your_table where DATE(timestamp_field) <> DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: @Elgoog: `<>` is "not equal to" in SQL. Another way of saying `!=`

Answer (score 0):

```
select something from table where DATE(unix_time) <> DATE(NOW())
```

<> does mean != (does not equal)