# Mysql date but not today

Tags: mysql

I have this database

id, date

How can make this day not show up?
 SELECT id, date FROM test WHERE?

```
 1 2018-08-28
 2 2018-08-29 
 3 2018-08-30
```

Comment: `WHERE \`date\` != '2018-08-28'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql query for all records not today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127708/mysql-query-for-all-records-not-today)

Comment: What is this day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
SELECT id, date FROM test WHERE DATE(`date`) <> CURDATE();
```

Comment: Much faster to use <> instead of using 'AND'

Answer (score 1):

```
select `id`,`date` from `test` where DATE(`date`) <> DATE(NOW())
```

Use **<>** which means not equal